# Using Java streams to get rid of a nested for loop

Tags: java, java-stream

I am iterating over two lists of different sizes:

```
List<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<>();
array1.add(20);
array1.add(17);
array1.add(52);
array1.add(12);
array1.add(8);
array1.add(5);
array1.add(24);


List<Integer> array2 = new ArrayList<>();
array2.add(13);
array2.add(18);
array2.add(10);
array2.add(6);
```

What I want to do is: iterate over both lists and pick out all the elements from array1, for which I can find an element in array2 that adds up with the element from array1 to yield a certain sum.

This is easy using a nested for-loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array2.size(); j++) {
        int sum = array1.get(i) + array2.get(j);
        if (sum == 30) {
           array3.add(array1.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

However, I want to get rid of the nested for-loop and use streams instead.

Does anyone have an idea how I could use streams for this case?

Comment: Put all of the elements of the second into a `Map<Integer, Integer>` counting the number of occurrences, and then in the outer loop create a `Collection.nCopies` and add to the result.

Comment: "However, I want to get rid of the nested for-loop and use streams instead." Why? For educational purposes, or because you think it would be better?

Comment: @AndyTurner: hmm... for educational purposes, I guess. I want to get more familiar with the stream API. Also, I really like the readability of streams. ... is it more efficient? My guess is it would be about the same performance, but I don't know that

Comment: streams are primarily for readability. It's hard for them to be more efficient because they use more "machinery" than a plain loop - even if they basically just wrap loops, that wrapping is "more".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the nested loop, I suggest you to use the stream API

```
List<Integer> result = array1.stream()
      .flatMap(el1 -> array2.stream()
                            .filter(el2 -> el1 + el2 == 30)
                            .map(el2 -> el1))
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: thx man, just what I was looking for! ... I was considering using `.anyMatch` . I was confused, because it returns a boolean, but now that I see it: ofc, `.filter` checks the stream using a predicate, so I have to give it a boolean.

Comment: This doesn't do the same as the nested loop in the face of duplicates in `array2`; that may or may not be desired, it's just not the same. Also, `el -> array2.contains(30 - el)` would be an easier predicate.

Comment: you are right @AndyTurner, I updated my answer to handle duplicates elements but I am not sure if it's the desired behavior

Answer (score 0):

Because you are just adding elements of the first list some number of times, you can collapse the inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.size(); i++) {
    // You are looking for things that sum to 30.
    // Equivalently, you are looking for elements in array2 equal to 30-element in array1.
    // And you end up adding as many times as there are occurrences.   
    int occurrences = Collections.frequency(array2, 30 - array1.get(i));

    // No need to (explicitly) loop to add this many, just create a list with that many elements, each equal to the element from array1.
    array3.addAll(Collections.nCopies(occurrences, array1.get(i)));
}
```

It doesn't matter if there is no such element in array2: the frequency will be zero, and `Collections.nCopies(0, element)` is an empty list.

You can do it with streams like so:

```
List<Integer> array3 =
    array1.stream()
        .map(a -> Collections.nCopies(Collections.frequency(array2, 30 - a)), a)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(toList());
```

Of course, this is inefficient in that the `frequency` call iterates `array2` fully for each element of `array1`. You can avoid that by building a map of element to frequency once (a `Map<Integer, Integer>`), and then looking up from that map instead.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<>();
array2.forEach(a -> frequencies.merge(a, 1, Integer::sum));

List<Integer> array3 =
    array1.stream()
        .map(a -> Collections.nCopies(frequencies.getOrDefault(30 - a, 0)), a))
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please?

Comment: There are too many `)` in the `.map()` lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get rid of nesting loops, you can try this way.

```
for(int i: array1) {
   int s = array2.indexOf(30-i);
   if(s != -1) {
     array3.add(i)
   }
}
```